# How to use Azure Access Control in Node.js

Tags: azure

Is there any node.js api for using Windows Azure Access Control from JavaScript (node.js)?

Comment: What exactly will you be doing with the access control service?

Comment: I was thinking about providing login option (LiveId, YahooId, gmail) for a web application developed in node.js and deployed in azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we don't have a npm package for this yet from the product team. It is on the team's radar, please keep an eye on our repo: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node.

There is a good community package that I think enables what you want to do: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth.

Comment: Is support available now in azure-sdk-for-node for acs authentication? If yes can you please provide related links.